# itextsharp: java to vb.net

Tags: java, vb.net, pdf, itext

i am trying to change the font on a pdftable and i have this hint in java but need some help to put it into vb.net

```
 PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(3);
    table.AddCell("Cell 1");
    PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Cell 2", new Font(Font.HELVETICA, 8f, Font.NORMAL, Color.YELLOW)));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Imports iTextSharp.text
Imports iTextSharp.text.pdf

Module Module1

    Sub Main()

        Dim table As New PdfPTable(3)
        table.AddCell("Cell 1")
        Dim f As New Font(Font.HELVETICA, 8.0F, Font.NORMAL, Color.YELLOW)
        Dim ph As New Phrase("Cell 2", f)
        Dim cell As New PdfPCell(ph)

    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: it says HELVETICA is not a member of system.drawing.font

Comment: In VB.NET, when 'Imports iTextSharp.text' is used, you can get a conflict because Visual Studio is confused about whether you want System.Drawing.Font or iTextSharp.text.Font.  Fully qualifying which Font object you want can resolve this.